# Upper/lower bound for $e$: $\left (\frac{n+1}{n}\right )^n\leq e$ using $e^n\ge 1+n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality, exponential-function

Provided the fact $e^n\geq 1+n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove the lower bound
$$\left (\frac{n+1}{n}\right )^n\leq e,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N} $$

from analysis we know, this is true.

Very first attempt fails miserably:
$$(n+1)^n\overset{?}\leq n^ne\Longrightarrow n+1\leq n\sqrt[n]{e} $$
provided fact is too weak to make any further progress on that attempt.

Next up: Binomial expansion
$$\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^n = \frac{1}{n^n}+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}} +\ldots +\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n}+1\overset{?}\leq e $$
This is how it's done in analysis, but I can't see how we make use of provided fact.

Hints would be most welcome on how to proceed.

Comment: What is your definition of $e$? If it is $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, you just have to apply AM-GM to deduce $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\leq\ldots\leq e.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
e^n \geq (n+1) \Rightarrow n \geq \log(n+1) \Rightarrow 1 \geq \frac{1}{n} \log(n+1) = \log{(n+1)^\frac{1}{n}}
$$
$$
m=\frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow 1 \geq \log{(\frac{1}{m}+1)^m}  \Rightarrow e \geq (\frac{1+m}{m})^m
$$

Comment: You are right. I did attempt this, too, but I abandoned it, because I thought the fact only held for all naturals, but I mis-read. It's given as for all reals.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that the binomial way is OK. I'd recommend trying
$$ \binom n k \leq n^k. $$
This can be seen easily with expanding the binomial coefficient:
$$ \binom n k = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2) \ldots (n-k+1)}{k!}.$$
Each of the parentheses is $\leq n$, there is $k$ of them, and the whole thing is divided by something $\geq 1$, so it should hold (at least if $n, k \leq 1$ and $0 \leq k \leq n$ — i. e. if the "normal" conditions for the coefficient hold).

From here you should be able to carry on yourself. If not, however, tell me and I can give more clues.

Answer (score 1):

Fact: $e^x\geq 1+x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
For lower bound, we take $x=\frac{1}{n},n\in\mathbb{N}$ and necessary result follows. We can get more than that, though. Pick $x=-\frac{1}{n+1},n\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$-\ln (1-\frac{1}{n+1})\geq \frac{1}{n+1}\iff \left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^{n+1}\geq e $$